# Why do Facebook buttons disappear in angular app on view change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I refresh the page they come back and work fine.  If i go to another "view" and go back they disappear.

They function fine when they are there.

```
 <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" ng-click="login()" >
      </fb:login-button>


<div class="fb-like" data-share="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
```

I'm going to implement this:https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky as it seems to address the issue.  But understanding why would help me plan future work.

**Bonus**: Comment on my approach to fix it or offer other suggestions.

EDIT: removing this: `ng-hide="isAuthenticated"` in the login-button, as this actually works and the effect im describing here happens regardless of it being there.

Comment: It seems your isAuthenticated which you are using to hide facebook buttons become true when you go to another view and come back.

Comment: I meant to remove that.  The behavior happens regardless of that that there.  Note the fb-like doesn't show up either.  Its def an angular/FB combo thing.  Going to remove it now.  Thanks tho.

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: No, they just don't show up when I toggle to another view and back.

Comment: hi, did you solve the issue?